# Hibernate join fetch on associated entity using @ManyToOne throws EntityNotFoundException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

Here is my entity models.

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "Folder")
 public class Folder implements Serializable{


     private User user;

     //unidirectional association
     @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
     @JoinColumn(name = "AssignedToUserID" ,nullable=true)
     public User getUser() {
        return user;
     }
 }

 @Entity
 @Table(name = "User")
 public class User implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "UserID")
    public Integer getUserId() {
      return this.userId;
    }
 }
```

Basically i want retrieve all folders together whether the folder has assigned user or not.

And here is my HQL query:

```
*SELECT folder from Folder folder inner join fetch folder.user user*

SQL generated By hibnermate:
    select
        folder0_.FolderID ,
        folder0_.FolderName ,
        folder0_.AssignedToUserID ,
        user_0.UserID ,
        user_0.UserName
    from
        Folder folder0_ 
    left outer join
        User user_0 
            on folder0_.AssignedToUserID=user_0.UserID
```

I wanted to eagerly load all associated entities, I really wanted to avoid the other select statements because it hurts performance and i am retrieving around 500k of records.

I am expecting that hibernate will return null instance when it sees that AssignedToUserID is NULL. But unfortunately it throws EntityNotFoundException though.

Am i missing something here? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Is there any more text with the 'EntityNotFoundException'? Often it is of the kind: EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find XXXXX with id XXXXXX. Also, can you check in your database whether table Folder has rows with AssignedToUserID's that do not exist in User?

Comment: Yes you are correct. Unable to find User with id 0. Ill check if there are any records that dont exist.

Comment: I think it means there is a Folder with AssignedToUserID=0

Comment: Its now working. It seems that i have missed out a record with id equal zero, but the last time i checked it there is none. But thank you so much its working now. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

> **left outer** join fetch folder.user user

Comment: Can you write what SQL query is performed?